# NullPointerException throws when i try to download files from FTP

Tags: java, android, ftp, inputstream

I'm trying to sequentially download two files  from FTP. First file download without any problems. But second throws NullPointerException when `InputStream` initialize with `ftpClient.retrieveFileStream()`. I've tried to change sequence, but it gave no effects. Files exists and avialible on FTP.

**CODE**

```
FTPClient ftpClient;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        String server = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "xxxxxx";
        String pass = "xxxxxx";
        long fileSize = 0;

        try {
            ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            fileSize += getFileSize(ftpClient, CARDS_DB);
            fileSize += getFileSize(ftpClient, IMG_DB);
            showDialog(PROGRESS_DLG_ID);
            downloadProgress.setMax((int) fileSize);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        final String PATH = getExternalCacheDir().toString() + "/";
        int total = 0;

        try {
            downloadFile(ftpClient, PATH, CARDS_DB, total);
            downloadFile(ftpClient, PATH, IMG_DB, total);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("EXCEPTION", e.toString());
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void downloadFile(FTPClient ftpClient, String PATH, String fileName, int total) {
        try {
            File downloadFile = new File(PATH + fileName);
            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(fileName); //here i have exception at second method invocation.

            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
                total += bytesRead;
                outputStream.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
                publishProgress(total);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
10-13 14:51:29.519 W/System.err(9554): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at com.FHS.ActivityMain$DBLoad.downloadFile(ActivityMain.java:170)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at com.FHS.ActivityMain$DBLoad.doInBackground(ActivityMain.java:141)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at com.FHS.ActivityMain$DBLoad.doInBackground(ActivityMain.java:102)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-13 14:51:29.529 W/System.err(9554):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

**SOLVED**
Problem solved. I just need to init FTPClient and open/close connections inside method at every invoke of method downloadFile().

Comment: Which line is `ActivityMain.java:170`?

Comment: @ssantos - he noted this in the source - look for a comment

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is masking your problem, which is that you aren't calling ftpClient.completePendingCommand() in downloadFile()  before closing your streams.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line of code:

```
final String PATH = getExternalCacheDir().toString() + "/";
```

because the method `getExternalCacheDir()` will **return you the cache dir only and only if cache is not empty**. If there is no cache, there will be no directory.

You could use `getExternalFilesDir()` instead.

Reference:

- [getExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29)
- [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

**EDIT:** Kindly modify the code to where initialize the ftpClient to :

```
int reply;
ftp.connect(server,port);
reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
```

and check the reply code.

Comment: Use of getExternalFilesDir() gave no effect. Same exception in same place.

Comment: Are you sure the FTP hsd more than two files..?

Comment: FTP has many files, but i want to load 2 files directly. No more. They are exist on server. But after first load - second throws exception.